# Extract an image using Python's Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I used the following code to extract an HTML I need from an Amazon listing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get("http://www.amazon.com/dp/B0007RXSB4")

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

soup.find_all("div", {"id":"imgTagWrapperId"})
```

Which gave me this:

```
[<div class="imgTagWrapper" id="imgTagWrapperId">\n<img alt="Johnston         
&amp; Murphy Men's Greenwich Oxford,Black,6 D" class="a-dynamic-image 
a-stretch-vertical" data-a-dynamic-image='{"http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY695_.jpg":
[695,695],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-
S._UY535_.jpg":[535,535],"http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY500_.jpg":
[500,500],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-
S._UY575_.jpg":[575,575],"http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY395_.jpg":
[395,395],"http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-
S._UY585_.jpg":[585,585]}' data-old-hires="http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UL1500_.jpg" id="landingImage" 
onload="this.onload='';setCSMReq('af');if(typeof addlongPoleTag === 
'function'){ addlongPoleTag('af','desktop-image-atf-
marker');};setCSMReq('cf')" src="http://ecx.images-
amazon.com/images/I/41KixMIlPNL._SY395_QL70_.jpg" style="max-
width:695px;max-height:695px;">\n</img></div>]
```

I just need to know how to extract

`http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY695_.jpg`

from the code above.

Answer (score 6):

First, you need to find the `img` tag inside the div you've already found. One way would be to chain the `find()` calls:

```
img = soup.find("div", {"id": "imgTagWrapperId"}).find("img")
```

Or, with a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
img = soup.select_one("div#imgTagWrapperId > img")
```

Then, if you need the image URL in the `src` attribute:

```
img["src"]
```

If you need the image URLs that are inside the `data-a-dynamic-image` attribute, I suggest you load the value into a python dictionary with `json` module and get the `keys()`:

```
import json

img = soup.find("div", {"id": "imgTagWrapperId"}).find("img")
data = json.loads(img["data-a-dynamic-image"])
print(list(data.keys()))
```

Prints:

```
[
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY695_.jpg',
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY575_.jpg',     
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY500_.jpg',     
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY395_.jpg',     
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY535_.jpg',     
    u'http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81zwayZox-S._UY585_.jpg'
]
```